# How do I select strings based on the number they end in?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of alphanumeric strings,

```
str = {"ANH7134UR1", "ANH7134UL4", "ANH7134UR7", "ANH7134UL17", "ANH7134UR18"};
```

that I want to assign each string to different variables based on a certain criteria. I want to assign any string that ends in 1-4 to `A`, any string that ends in 5-15 to `B` and any string that ends in 16-20 to `C`.

Comment: Do you have any code you would like to share with us ?

Answer (score 3):

I'd go for

```
str = {"ANH7134UR1", "ANH7134UL4", "ANH7134UR7", "ANH7134UL17", "ANH7134UR18"};

strRangePattern[min_, max_] := Apply[Alternatives, ToString /@ Range[min, max]]

test[end_][str_] := StringMatchQ[str, ___ ~~ LetterCharacter .. ~~ end]

ranges = {strRangePattern[1, 4], strRangePattern[5, 15], strRangePattern[16, 20]};

{a, b, c} = Select[str, test[#]] & /@ ranges;
```

or here is another solution:

```
ending[str_] := ToExpression@StringReplace[str, ___ ~~ LetterCharacter .. ~~ end__ :> end];

groupNumber[val_] := Which[
  Between[val, {1, 4}], 1,
  Between[val, {5, 15}], 2,
  Between[val, {16, 20}], 3
  ]

{a, b, c} = GatherBy[str, groupNumber@*ending]
```

(Though for this solution there is nothing that guarantees which elements belong to `a`, `b` and `c` respectively. Just that they are separated.)

Comment: As I have understood the question, `ANH7134UL17` and `ANH7134UR18` should only come in the your `c` right because it ends in `17` & `18` respectively or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: @Hubble07 You are right, I corrected it.

Comment: But it is still giving the same result as earlier.

Comment: @Hubble07 Thank you again! I'm so clumsy today; now it should work finally. I tested it.

Comment: The second solution only works if the `str` list is sorted (by the tail number).

Comment: @Aisamu That is exactly what I warned about in my comment underneath the solution. I just wanted to display this solution as well, I might have preferred it if I only had three categories and was just exploring because then it's easy to see which subset ends up where.

Comment: @C.E. I mentioned it because the answer asks for a specific-variable assignment, implying that the ordering is essential for a proper solution

Comment: @Aisamu My point in my comment was that if this is a one time thing you can just try it, and if it didn't turn out right you can rearrange the order of the variables in the assignment. The latter solution is easier to understand which is very desirable, because the reason that people ask questions is because they are new to Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

Define all your ranges

```
str = {"ANH7134UR1", "ANH7134UL4", "ANH7134UR7", "ANH7134UL17", "ANH7134UR18"};
min[1] = 1; max[1] = 4; min[2] = 5; max[2] = 15; min[3] = 16; max[3] = 20;
range[i_] := Range[min[i], max[i]];
```

Then the idea is to first find all the `Characters` in each string then `Reverse` them all and look for the `FirstPosition` of a letter using `LetterQ`. Subtract 1 to get the number of digits at the end. Use `StringTake` to take those last numbers. Finally use `ContainsAny` to check which range contains those number and `Select` them accordingly.

```
{var1, var2, var3} = Table[Select[str, 
ContainsAny[
range[i], {ToExpression[
  StringTake[#, -((First@
        FirstPosition[Reverse@Characters[#], _?LetterQ] - 1))]]}] &],
{i, 1, 3}]

(*{{"ANH7134UR1", "ANH7134UL4"}, {"ANH7134UR7"}, {"ANH7134UL17", "ANH7134UR18"}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're treating the string tail as a number range, I'd recommend casting it and grouping accordingly.

```
str = {"ANH7134UR1", "ANH7134UL4", "ANH7134UR7", "ANH7134UL17", "ANH7134UR18"};

ClearAll[myGrouping];
myGrouping[s_String] := 
 First @ StringCases[s, 
   Shortest[__] ~~ n : Repeated[DigitCharacter, {1, 2}] ~~ EndOfString
    :> myGrouping@ToExpression@n]

myGrouping[n_Integer] := "varA" /; Between[n, {1, 4}]
myGrouping[n_Integer] := "varB" /; Between[n, {5, 15}]
myGrouping[n_Integer] := "varC" /; Between[n, {16, 20}]

GroupBy[str, myGrouping]

(* <|"varA" -> {"ANH7134UR1", "ANH7134UL4"},
     "varB" -> {"ANH7134UR7"}, 
     "varC" -> {"ANH7134UL17", "ANH7134UR18"}|> *)

(* Clear and assign to variables *)
KeyMap[ClearAll, %]  
KeyValueMap[Set, KeyMap[Symbol, %%]]

varA
(* {"ANH7134UR1", "ANH7134UL4"} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Between` and `Through` for the selection instead.

With

```
str = {"ANH7134UR1", "ANH7134UL4", "ANH7134UR7", "ANH7134UL17", "ANH7134UR18"};
varRng = {{1, 4}, {5, 15}, {16, 20}};
```

Then

```
{a, b, c} =
 Keys@
  Through@(Select[Between[#]] & /@ varRng)[
    Association @@ (
      # -> First@
          StringCases[#, 
           Shortest[__] ~~ n : DigitCharacter .. ~~ EndOfString :> FromDigits@n] & /@ str
      )
    ]

(* {{"ANH7134UR1", "ANH7134UL4"}, {"ANH7134UR7"}, {"ANH7134UL17", "ANH7134UR18"}} *)
```

The `StringCases` of this is similar to @Aisamu post (though independently constructed). `Select` is used with `Between` to get the groupings.  This makes a selection for each of the groupings but it is using all built-in functions so it should be fast enough.

Hope this helps.